# How to use XmlNamespaceManager and SelectSingleNode correctly?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I need to get node value from xml. The xml has namespace.

I have the following code

```
string xml =
    "<file xmlns=\"SFAKT\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
    "<document>test</document>" +
    "</file>";

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("sf", "SFAKT");
XmlNode node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("sf:file/document");
```

But node = **null**

Can you tell me where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the overloaded `SelectSingleNode` method and pass in the `XmlNamespaceManager`.  Also, you need the sf prefix for the document node.

Pull the node out like this:

```
XmlNode node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("sf:file/sf:document", ns);
```